# Assigning CSS value to SASS variable

Tags: css, sass

Is there a way to directly assign a CSS value to a SASS variable, like this:

```
$var:padding: 20px/1440px * 100%;
```

I know that I can to this:

```
$padding: 20px/1440px * 100%;
padding: $padding;
```

But is there a way to directly assign a value in CSS to a variable? Basically to have it on a same line.

Comment: No.  This is what mixins are for.

Answer (score 3):

not possible to use a variable directly, you could use a mixin instead:

```
@mixin pad{padding: 20px/1440px * 100%;}
.div-with-padding{@include pad;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gTsG9/

Answer (score 0):

You could assign a css value like a string:

```
$var:"padding: 20px/1440px * 100%";
```

But I really don't know how is this going to help you. Mixin is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

**no its not possible to assign directly from the variable. you have to use mixin for that.**

sample :

```
@mixin ur_padding
{
padding:20px/1440px * 100%
}

.ur_div_here
{
@include ur_padding;
}
```